# iPhone won't connect in Xcode 6 beta

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8

I updated both iOS 8 and Xcode 6 beta. When I connect my phone, it shows up as "**ineligible device**" where you select which platform you want to run on.

When I try to run the project on my actual iPhone, an error message in Xcode appears that says:

> An error was encountered while enabling development on this device.

If anyone knows how I can fix this, I would much appreciate it because I haven't found much info on this error message.

Comment: You might want to mark an answer complete since I see you have solved the issue.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I've had the same problem. I closed Xcode made sure my phone was connected then reloaded Xcode and that worked for me.

Comment: actually this along didn't work for me with Xcode 6 Beta 7, but doing both what @dominik and this one resolved my issue. Thanks both of you.

Comment: Sometimes Apple is so Microsoft it's scary... shocked and happy for that answer, worked for me, too.

Answer (score 11):

For me changing the Command Line Tools to Xcode 6 (instead of Xcode 5.1.1) under "Preferences" -- "Locations" -- "Command Line Tools" did the trick..

[image]

Comment: This one makes a lot of sense! It helped me. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

XCode proposes restarting the device and that doesn't work. Instead restarting XCode itself did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

After installing new version Xcode, propose install additional components for debugging. If these components not installed, propose Xcode again for installation. Simplest way to check for existence of required components:

1. Relaunch Xcode
2. Install required components

This is worked for me!

Comment: What are the "required components" ? Why would you restart xCode before installing them ?

Comment: 1) After install new version xCode propose install addition components for debugging. This "additional content" is "required components". 
2) After relaunch xCode again propose install this components if they no be installed.

Comment: Edit your answer to reflect theses details.

Comment: Done. My answer was helpful for you?

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone! Problem was solved for me by restarting my iPhone and Xcode

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck on this for forever.  Make sure that you didn't choose "Don't Trust" with the computer.  If you did, then you will need to make the prompt come up again, and choose "Trust".  If your phone is jailbroken, make sure you don't have any tweak (NoAnnoyance for me) that auto chooses "Don't Trust".