# iPhone not listed in the Xcode Organizer

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have researched into this nasty issue but all I found was issues with iTunes not recognizing a device, or with Xcode having intermittent issues with provisioning the iPhone. In my case nothing helped! I re-installed iTunes, Xcode 6 beta 6 and plugged/unplugged my iPhone 5 after each installation or restart, to no avail. The screen shot below shows my iPhone listed in Devices but it is not listed in the Organizer. Also, any new project I create for the iPhone, it shows my iPhone under "Ineligible Devices" as you can see in the screen shot. I am at a loss what else to try.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Definitely try restarting xcode and your computer. There should be a pop up on your phone when you plug it in that says "Trust this computer?"

Comment: I restarted Xcode and my MBP several times. Is this pop-up meant to show only when Xcode is open or every time? Because I connect my phone to charge it every day and I've never seen such a pop-up or maybe it happened once, 2 years ago when I bought the phone, but I certainly forgot if that ever happened.

Comment: When you have xcode open this should happen. It is meant as a check for developers when attempting to use a device for development. Is your iPhone iOS 7?

Comment: This should happen every time I open Xcode or just the first time? I have used my iPhone 5 (iOS 7.1) with Xcode 5 before but today was the first time I used with Xcode 6. no pop-ups though.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can't use an iOS 7 device with Xcode 6 unless you symlink the iOS 7 SDK to Xcode 6

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045307/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-7-sdk-on-xcode-6

Comment: I don't know what I did but the project now runs on my iPhone with iOS 7.1 even though it still doesn't show in the Organizer. so I can use my iPhone running iOS 7 even though that link says I would not be able to.

Answer (score 0):

Your project's deployment target is probably 8.0 and your device is 7.1.2. Check you Info.plist and make sure it's the same or lower version than your device OS version.

Comment: the deployment target for that Hello project is 7.1 just like the iOS version on my phone. what you see in the screen shot though is the SDK version Xcode 6 comes with. I'm not sure that can be even changed.

Comment: try restarting xcode or your computer. though a few found success through updating your Command Line Tool path http://stackoverflow.com/a/24291473/1563181

Comment: the CLT path was already at version 6 and it's the only choice I have listed.