# Getting an error after updating to iOS version 9.2.1?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I've recently updated iOS version 9.2.1 on my iPhone 5s. After the update was installed i can't deploy an app to my device and got this error message.
[image]

I use xcode version 7.1.1 and have never made any change of my source code.
How can i fix this problem without downgrading my phone, or anything i can do to resolve the problem? Many thanks.

Comment: Probably has something to do with you not using the latest Xcode version, which is 7.2.1 right now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233220/iphone-wont-connect-in-xcode-6-beta

Comment: In order to test on a 9.2.1 device you need Xcode 7.2.

Comment: I will try to update Xcode to 7.2 thanks man :)